# Why are these dependent and independent events respectively.

Tags: probability

> Case #1.

P(A) is the probability of rolling a fair standard dice and getting numbers less than or equal to **4**.

P(B) is the probability of rolling it and getting even numbers.

> Case #2.

P(A) is the probability of rolling a fair standard dice and getting numbers less than or equal to **3**.

P(B) is the probability of rolling it and getting even numbers.

Here, in the case #1, A and B are independent while in the case #2 they are dependent. I know how to calculate both of them, but I don't understand it intuitively. How come they come out so differently just by adjusting a number? Shouldn't independent cases be like the relation between winning a lottery and having a bug bite? And shouldn't dependent cases be like the relation between eating rotten food and getting a stomach ache?

Comment: @PeterForeman Thanks but I said I know how to calculate it. Dependent event means one case affect the other. Just how does P(A) in the case #2 affect P(B)??

Comment: Not sure there's much intuition to be had here...as you remark, it comes down to the computation. To the question in your comment though...knowing that you threw $≤3$ greatly increases the probability that you threw an odd number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dependence doesn't imply causation.  Intuitively, two events are independent if knowing that one occurs gives you no information about whether the other will occur.  If we know that the number is $\leq4$, well, half the numbers from $1$ to $4$ are even, so there's still a $50\%$ chance of getting an even number; the information doesn't change our assessment in nay way.  But suppose we learn that the number is $\leq3$.  Now there are two odd numbers possible, and only one even number, so the probability of getting an even number has changed to $\frac13.$

Answer (score 1):

For case #1.:

Portion of evens in numbers less then 4 equals portion of evens in numbers more then 4.

The same in other words: To be even have same chances  when we consider numbers less then 4 $\left( \frac{1}{2} \right)$ as to be even when we consider numbers more then 4 $\left( \frac{1}{2} \right)$- so these events are independent. By the event be less or more then 4 you cannot affect (change chances) for event to be even.

Comment: Thanks but I said I know how to calculate it. Dependent event means one case affect the other. Just how does P(A) in the case #2 affect P(B)??

Comment: @user800956. I adjusted answer.

Answer (score 1):

Related and dependent are not the same thing. They are only dependent if the outcome of one changes the probabilities of the other event.

Case 1:
P(A | B) = P(x <= 4 | x is even) = $\frac{2}{3}$
P(A) = P(x <= 4) = $\frac{4}{6} = \frac{2}{3}$

Case 2:
P(A | B) = P(x <= 3 | x is even) = $\frac{1}{3}$
P(A) = P(x <= 3) = $\frac{1}{2}$

In case one, knowing B doesn't change the likelihood of A, while in case 2 it does. Dependence isn't about if events are related, but if knowing one changes your predictions of the other

Another good example is:

A: Chance of the first of two coin flips being heads
B: Chance of the same two coin flips being different

P(B|A) = P(Two coin flips are different|first is heads) = P(second is tails) = $\frac{1}{2}$

P(B) = P(two heads) + P(two tails) = $\frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{4}$ = $\frac{1}{2}$

These events are clearly related, but knowing one doesn't change the probability of the other